# Robotics Structure

Tags: sensors, first-robotics

I am a kind of a new developer and a beginner in Robotics and AI. I am currently learning using the Arduino Uno starter kit. My knowledge on C & C++ is on the beginner's level but i get the whole idea and flow of data.


I want to build a mini robot that can behave as a pedestrian. Navigate within a city as a pedestrian using a GPS system. It will have to "walk" any kind of terrain that it will encounter in a city e.g pavement, stairs e.t.c.


My question is, having in mind that it will never have to charge itself, what is the best build system in order for that robot to be able to do that? What kind of sensors will be needed apart from camera(visual)?


I know this is a very general question. I am very new to this so please bare with me. Any information and guidance much appreciated.

Comment: `will never have to charge itself` ... go with a nuclear reactor on this one

Comment: `What kind of sensors will be needed apart from camera?` ... go for a walk around the city and make a note of the sensors that you use

Comment: thank you @jsotola

Comment: You can think about using a LIDAR sensor. Camera might not be sufficient enough to perceive your surroundings, so you may use LIDARs and maybe ultrasonic sensors. Also if you are going to use a GPS system, you need to have some kind of IMU sensor which is going to optimize your robot's GPS position.

Comment: Thank you @kucar.  I will study what you mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [Duckietown](https://www.duckietown.org/) project.  It is a robot (the Duckiebot) and an urban environment for learning about robotics and autonomy.  There is an [Edx MOOC and curriculum](https://www.edx.org/course/self-driving-cars-with-duckietown) designed for undergraduate university level.  The Duckiebot can be purchased as a kit from the Duckietown org, or you can build your own [DIYDuckie](https://github.com/Ezward/diyduckie).  Duckiebot is based on Python and ROS2 and and is [open source](https://github.com/duckietown).  ROS is pretty complex for an introduction to robots.  You might also try [Donkeycar](https://www.donkeycar.com/) which is a popular python framework for creating autonomous racing cars from an RC (I'm a maintainer on that project).  As a first robot, this [project](https://github.com/Ezward/Esp32CameraRover2) that I created is easy to build and inexpensive (about $40 in parts); it includes a camera and can be extended in JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you Ezward, i will have a look at those. Thank you for your contribution in open source. I will accept this as an answer for the time being.